# How To Increase Static Buffer Size in Ink 5.0 Contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract

In Ink 5.0, the Static Buffer size can be increased. Does anyone know HOW to do that? This PR mentions several methods they were considering: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1869

I tried the option `cargo contract build --static-buffer-size 32768 --release` but cargo-contract did not recognize `--static-buffer-size`

There is mention in the above PR that it might be implemented in the cargo.toml instead, but no discussion of HOW. Does anyone know the magic to make this great new feature work in ink 5.0?

Comment: AND... what is the largest you could reasonably make the static buffer?